# trigger click on data target modal does not trigger show.bs.modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, eventtrigger

I'm trying to open a bootstrap modal automatically based on whether a particular query string exists in the url or not. I do this by calling trigger('click') on the button that normally opens the modal when clicking on it:

```
<a href="" id="openmodal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>
$("#openmodal").trigger('click');
```

The modal opens fine, but the problem is that the following event which normally gets triggered when a modal is opened is not triggering anymore when the modal is opened with trigger click:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#myModal', function(e){
    // This does not get fired anymore
});
```

Any idea why the show.bs.modal event does not get fired when calling trigger('click') on the modal open button?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your event binding needs to be before the trigger code, like the following:

```js
$(function() {
    // You can also do
    // $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#myModal', function(e) {
        console.info(e);
    });
    
    $("#openmodal").trigger('click');
});
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/g51aLcxr/7/